# i want to enable drawing on whole website but i could not because drawing possible in only canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawing

I want to draw using mouse cursor in my whole website but i could not find any way to do it. i only one thing in google that using canvas i can achieve that but i cant take my whole website inside canvas and even if i do that it is not working. what i am trying to do is to pase my whole website code under the canvas and make canvas width and height 100% but it is not working and so doodling. 
here the code for that canvas drawing

```js
// Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context
var canvas,ctx;

// Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status 
var mouseX,mouseY,mouseDown=0;

// Draws a dot at a specific position on the supplied canvas name
// Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot
function drawDot(ctx,x,y,size) {
  // Let's use black by setting RGB values to 0, and 255 alpha (completely opaque)
  r=0; g=0; b=0; a=255;

  // Select a fill style
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";

  // Draw a filled circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
} 

// Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height
function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
function sketchpad_mouseDown() {
  mouseDown=1;
  drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being released
function sketchpad_mouseUp() {
  mouseDown=0;
}

// Keep track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed
function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) { 
  // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
  getMousePos(e);

  // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
  if (mouseDown==1)
    drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
}

// Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
function getMousePos(e) {
  if (!e)
    var e = event;

  if (e.offsetX) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
  } else if (e.layerX) {
    mouseX = e.layerX;
    mouseY = e.layerY;
  }
}


// Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded
function init() {
  // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
  canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

  // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas
  if (canvas.getContext)
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
  if (ctx) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);
  }
}
```

```css
#sketchpadapp {
        /* Prevent nearby text being highlighted when accidentally dragging mouse outside confines of the canvas */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        }
        .leftside {
        float:left;
        width:220px;
        height:285px;
        background-color:#def;
        padding:10px;
        border-radius:4px;
        }
        .rightside {
        float:left;
        margin-left:10px;
        }
        #sketchpad {
        float:left;
        border:2px solid #888;
        border-radius:4px;
        position:relative; /* Necessary for correct mouse co-ords in Firefox */
        }
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="sketchpadapp">
        <div class="leftside">
            Simple mouse-based HTML5 canvas sketchpad.<br/><br/>
            Draw something by holding down the mouse button or using single clicks.<br/><br/>
            On a touchscreen, tapping the area will register as a single mouse click.<br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <canvas id="sketchpad" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
              <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="z-index:999999999;">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/amitchauh4n/pen/NvjryG

Answer (score 0):

So what you miss is the following function that sizes the canvas:

```
function updateCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

The canvas drawing is demolished by the following style in the canvas tag:

```
<canvas id="sketchpad" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
```

Further I edited this css block:

```
#sketchpad {
  float:left;
  border:2px solid #888;
  border-radius:4px;
  position:relative; /* Necessary for correct mouse co-ords in Firefox */
}
```

To this:

```
#sketchpad {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is a snippet how to draw full screen on a website.

```js
// Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context
var canvas,ctx;

// Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status 
var mouseX,mouseY,mouseDown=0;

// Draws a dot at a specific position on the supplied canvas name
// Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot
function drawDot(ctx,x,y,size) {
  // Let's use black by setting RGB values to 0, and 255 alpha (completely opaque)
  r=0; g=0; b=0; a=100;

  // Select a fill style
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";

  // Draw a filled circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
} 

// Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height
function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
function sketchpad_mouseDown() {
  mouseDown=1;
  drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being released
function sketchpad_mouseUp() {
  mouseDown=0;
}

// Keep track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed
function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) { 
  // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
  getMousePos(e);

  // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
  if (mouseDown==1)
    drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
}

// Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
function getMousePos(e) {
  if (!e)
    var e = event;

  if (e.clientX && e.clientY) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
  }
}


// Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded
function init() {
  // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
  canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

  // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas
  if (canvas.getContext)
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
  if (ctx) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);
  }
  
  updateCanvas()
}

function updateCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

```css
.leftside {
  float:left;
  width:220px;
  height:285px;
  background-color:#def;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:4px;
}
.rightside {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#sketchpad {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sketchpadapp">
  <div class="leftside">
    Simple mouse-based HTML5 canvas sketchpad.
    <br/><br/>
    Draw something by holding down the mouse button or using single clicks.
    <br/><br/>
    On a touchscreen, tapping the area will register as a single mouse click.<br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <canvas id="sketchpad"></canvas>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="z-index:999999999;">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 3</h3>        
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

However some issues that you need to fix what in my opinion is not the primary problem you had.

1. Interaction with the web site [clicking buttons].
2. That the drawing is bound to the scroll position.

If you want these issues fixed I am sure stack overflow can help with it by asking a new question.